# Freeswitch : Load Testing for Call Broadcasting

Tags: sip, asterisk, voip, freeswitch

I have a freeswitch server . my scenario is Call broadcasting about n sip users. how can i test the server stability in high load (load testing) using sipp tester. what number i must dial in dialplan (or lua)? what scenario i must use in sipp side?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to call MOH ("hold-music") extension, in basic FS configuration it's number 9664 in default context.
You will get the answer and RTP from FS side. If you want to use LUA, you can create this lua file (modified "hello lua" example from FS wiki)

```
-- answer the call
session:answer();

-- play a file
session:streamFile("/path/to/blah.wav");
```

Yes, there's no hangup. Session will stay forever until FS is crashed or calls are dropped manually. Obviously, WAV file should be long enough.

But I don't think that LUA is needed here, MOH extension should be enough for simple test. Probably you will have to set a codec strictly, because different codecs use different bandwidth.

You also can find scenarios here http://www.freeswitch.org/eg/load_test/ but they're **really** old.